# How to use Static Variable to save a string in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, static

I want to use Static Var to save a NSString.
So I define a Static Var in a .h file like this:

```
#ifndef GlobalParameters_h
#define GlobalParameters_h

//access token
static NSString *applicationToken;

#endif
```

In class A, I change the static var like this:

```
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "GlobalParameters.h"

extern NSString *applicationToken;

@implementation ClassA

+ (void)parseResponse:(NSString *)response
{
    NSDictionary *responseDic = [response objectFromJSONString];

    NSString *token = [responseDic objectForKey:@"token"];

    applicationToken = [token copy];

    NSLog(@"%@",applicationToken);
}
```

When the debugger run to

```
applicationToken = [token copy];
```

I found the "applicationToken" is nil,but the next sentence

```
NSLog(@"%@",applicationToken);
```

can output the right value in console! And in ClassB , the "applicationToken" is nil too.
I don't know why the static var is nil. I think the compiler will find the definition of "applicationToken" in GlobalParameters.h.But why I can't modify the static value?

Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` global variable mean that it's own for every object-file it's used. So there is willbe own applicationToken for ClassA, ClassB.

To create global variable for all object-files you need this:

In GlobalParameters.h:

```
#ifndef GlobalParameters_h
#define GlobalParameters_h

//access token
extern NSString *applicationToken;

#endif
```

In GlobalRarameters.m:

```
#import "GlobalParameters.h"

NSString *applicationToken;
```

P.S. I hope you use ARC, because if not, then `applicationToken = [token copy];` will cause memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for your help.But,I use the keyword "extern". I remember that "extern" could expand the scope of the var.

Comment: @Tsich'i, ok. use `extern`, just don't use `static`.

Comment: In GlobalParameters_h , I modify "staic NSString *applicationToken" to "NSString *applicationToken" . Then in ClassA ,"applicationToken" can be modified correctly. Is there any posibilities the "applicationToken" be released during MyApp is running? @Cy-4AH

Comment: I hope "applicationToken" can be used during MyApp is running.

Comment: @Tsich'i, I have already wrote in which file how should be defined yours variable, why you doesn't use it?

Answer (score 0):

- Hey Its working fine , I am checking like this

  Once check the are you getting  "responseDic" (or) not , Check the
  The dictionary have token key

> ```
>    static NSString *applicationToken;
>    applicationToken = @"srinivas";
>    NSLog(@"%@",applicationToken);
>
>    NSDictionary *responseDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"static" forKey:@"token"];
>
>    NSString *token = [responseDic objectForKey:@"token"];
>
>    applicationToken = [token copy];
>
>    NSLog(@"%@",applicationToken);
>        [AppDelegate parseResponse:responseDic];
> ```

Comment: Yes, I check the value. The "token" has the correct value. But when I set the value to the static "applicationToken" , it's failure.